# Unable to separate PdfPTable footer rows from the table header

Tags: java, pdf, header, itext, footer

I followed the example from Chapter 4 in "iText in Action", which uses table.setHeaderRows() and table.setFooterRows(). When I use these same methods, all of the rows appear in the header. I call these methods after adding all of the header and footer cells (which make up the rows), but before adding any other cells to the table. I don't think it would be particularly helpful to include all of my code that does this.  But I'd be happy to clarify anything that I might have left out of this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I forgot that the rows in the header belong to a sub-table within a single cell (row), so I passed the wrong value to setHeaderRows().